# enableEventValidation error

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a cascade dropdownlist that is populated by client side using jquery and Ajax.
The values of dropdown are read from database using Ajax.
I get enableEventValidation error when post back occurs.
One of my options is to use the page
directive enableEventValidation="false". but I don't want to do it.
so what's the soloution

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use [ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms223397.aspx) to allow your DropDown to change it's items on clientside?

```
Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(DropDownList1.UniqueID)
   MyBase.Render(writer)
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work, this is my code:

protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(DpState.UniqueID);
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(DpCity.UniqueID);
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(DpDistrict.UniqueID);
        base.Render(writer);
    }